# Python GPU Resource Utilization

Tags: python, gpu

I have a Python script running inference on some deep learning models.

Is there any way I can find out the GPU resource utilization levels? For instance, utilization of shaders, float16 multipliers, etc.

I can't seem to find much documentation online regarding those GPU resources.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run your pyxthon-application in a GPU-Profiler like Renderdoc. It will analyse you your run. You will be able to get information about th eused resources, used buffers, output on the different renderstates etc.

Just check [Renderdoc-website](https://renderdoc.org/) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with [pynvml](https://github.com/gpuopenanalytics/pynvml) and if you are using jupyterlab you could use [nvdashboard](https://github.com/rapidsai/jupyterlab-nvdashboard).  A recent medium post details the usage of these libraries: https://medium.com/rapids-ai/gpu-dashboards-in-jupyter-lab-757b17aae1d5